# Sonarqube does not load its page without any error message when connected to PostgresQL

Tags: sonarqube

> Blockquote

I installed sonarqube and postgresql. When I comment postgresql url, username and password in sonar.properties file, sonarqube loads its page without any issue. But sonarqube does not load its page as soon as  postgresql username, password and url are uncommented in sonar.properties page. Below is the configuration and sonarqube error log. Please help.

```
sonar.jdbc.username
sonar.jdbc.password
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9000/sonarqube


2017.05.22 01:22:57 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2017.05.22 01:22:57 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2017.05.22 01:22:57 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1495430576840] version[2.3.3], pid[18065], build[218bdf1/2016-05-17T15:40:04Z]
2017.05.22 01:22:57 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1495430576840] initializing ...
2017.05.22 01:22:57 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1495430576840] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2017.05.22 01:22:57 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1495430576840] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)]], net usable_space [9.8gb], net total_space [19.9gb], spins? [unknown], types [rootfs]
2017.05.22 01:22:57 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1495430576840] heap size [1007.3mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2017.05.22 01:22:57 WARN   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1495430576840] max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
2017.05.22 01:22:59 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1495430576840] initialized
2017.05.22 01:22:59 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1495430576840] starting ...
2017.05.22 01:22:59 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1495430576840] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
2017.05.22 01:22:59 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1495430576840] sonarqube/LJ_FLAsuTKqVBqSqY43J9g
2017.05.22 01:23:02 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1495430576840] new_master {sonar-1495430576840}{LJ_FLAsuTKqVBqSqY43J9g}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}{rack_id=sonar-1495430576840}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
2017.05.22 01:23:02 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1495430576840] started
2017.05.22 01:23:02 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1495430576840] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
2017.05.22 01:23:03 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.allocation]  [sonar-1495430576840] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[tests][4], [tests][0]] ...]).
2017.05.22 01:23:03 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2017.05.22 01:23:03 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube-6.0/temp -javaagent:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonarqube-6.0/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonarqube-6.0/temp/sq-process3487714092659899450properties
2017.05.22 01:23:04 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2017.05.22 01:23:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: /opt/sonarqube-6.0/web
2017.05.22 01:23:04 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2017.05.22 01:23:04 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2017.05.22 01:23:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 6.0 / 93442889cd219e78b028c7dcf51a30de74c987fe
2017.05.22 01:23:04 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9000/sonarqube
```

Comment: No value specified for sonar.jdbc.username and sonar.jdbc.password. If you skipped copying here intentionally (just to hide credentials from us), then its ok

Comment: It was intentional. I could have put something on username and password but I did not think it was necessary. Anyway, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JDBC URL does not seems correct : is your postgresql instance listening on port 9000, default port is 5432 ?
9000 port is used by SonarQube to expose its http port.

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.